# Using a Jquery plugin in a dynamically loaded view using rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a control bar on my application that has popovers with dynamically loaded partial views (using `#{j render :partial =>'layouts/popover_partial'}` ). I want to use a jQuery script to auto grow a textbox but can't seem to get it to work. How can I make sure that the jQuery autogrow script is included with my dynamically loaded view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript for a specific View (let's say View = bamboo), will be stored in,

```
/app/assests/javascripts/bamboo.js.coffee
```

Notice you will want to translate your JQuery JavaScript into CoffeeScript format. See the coffee [script site](http://coffeescript.org/) for how to do that.

If you want the JavaScript to be call-able for any view, put it in,

```
/app/assests/javascripts/application.js
```